# Registering ATG component with Jersey REST api framework

Tags: jersey-2.0, atg, atg-dynamo, oracle-commerce

I am having a component that i want to use in my Jersey rest api without using request.resolve. 
My web.xml looks like this

```
<!-- Jersey servlet configuration -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>JerseyRESTServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.cellularsouth.rest.SetApplication</param-value>
        </init-param>
         <!-- Params for JerseyServletWrapper servlet -->

        <init-param>
            <param-name>atg.service.jaxrs.JAXRSApplication.resourceRegistryPath</param-name>
            <param-value>/atg/service/jaxrs/RestResourceRegistry</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>JerseyRESTServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest-api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

I have created `RestResouceRegistry.properties` and gave my component file location like this-

```
nucleusRestResources+=\
/rest/api/account/Billing
```

But i dont see RestResouceRegistry.properties in my **dyn/admin**. Can someone please help me figure out what am i missing ?

Comment: Are all your paths correct? OOTB the `RestResourceRegistry` resides in `/atg/dynamo/service/jaxrs/RestResourceRegistry`

Comment: i have tried changing the path to /atg/dynamo/service/jaxrs/RestResourceRegistry but still didnt work

Comment: We found the reason RestResourceRegistry didnt work for us. We were using ATG 11.2 and this is supported only from ATG 11.3 :(

Comment: Which it is why it is important to specify which version of a package/tool you are using when asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

Either change the path of your service to the default JAX-RS path or change 
`JerseyClassLoaderService.properties` to something like:

```
childFirstPrefixes=+\
              /my/custom/service/path
```